# SQL, find an ID which contains 2 values in 2 lines

Tags: sql, select, mysqli

My BDD looks like that :

id_feature | id_product | id_feature_value

```
 1          1               20
 2          2               21
 3          3               20
 4          2               20
```

I need to get the product which have id_Feature_Value 20 AND 21.

I can't find the rigth syntax the have my result...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how to do.

My request check all the product which have the value 20 OR 21. Si if they have the two values, the id_product will be display twice because there is no group by.

I just had to add a where clause with HAVE(`id_product`) > 1

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select
  a.id_product
from
  yourtable a,
  yourtable b
where
  a.id_product=b.id_product and
  a.id_feature_value=20 and
  b.id_feature_value=21
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I only have 1 table so I don't see what to put un table b

Comment: nothing. The a and b are only the aliases for the same table. I modified a bit the query.